# use a python package in a ctypes python wrapper

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a c file by name `detection.c` for which I have created a `python wrapper` using `ctypes`. The input to the C code is an array. The python script I have written extracts the array from the file and passes the array to the C code. While reading I have used the `numpy` package while including the `numpy` in the python script it throws this error.

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wno-error -fpic detection.c
gcc -shared -o libdetection.so detection.o
./python_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_script.py", line 5, in <module>
   import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

**python_script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
import os 
import sys
import numpy as np


libc = ctypes.CDLL("./libdetection.so")
libc.detect.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
```

Comment: numpy doesn't come installed with Python.  There are variations on installing 3rd party packages, but try `pip3 install numpy` or `python3 -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: I already have numpy installed in my system.

Comment: If I comment `import numpy as np`, the makefile complies fine. But I get the error `np not defined` when I run the python script.